# How do I set the start URL of a Visual Studio project globally?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, csproj

I need to change the start URL of a project. When I set the start URL on the property page, it gets written to the `csproj.user` file and not the `csproj`. I tried putting the `<StartExternalURL>` in the `csproj` in the `<WebProjectProperties>` section, but that did not work.

Is there any way I can set that property and propagate it to the entire team, or is everyone just going to have to make the change manually?

Comment: 10 years on... I want to do the same thing. I tried adding <StartExternalURL> to the csproj, but VS2019 ignores it unless it is in the csproj.user. Sucks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `csproj.user` file under source control. When everyone checks it out, their start URL will be set correctly.

Comment: `.user` files are just that, settings made by the user which differ from the settings of the project. In most cases the `.user` files will have been added to the `.tfignore` or `.gitignore`. The problem with putting this file in source control is that people will overwrite it constantly if they forget to exclude the change, which also affects other users because their settings are getting overwritten by somebody else's.

Comment: @Chrono that is a valid concern, but I find the `.user` file does not contain many settings or those settings do not change all the time, so the nuisance is limited. Still, it is the simplest solution to achieve what the OP wants. I guess you could experiment with source control triggers to alter the file after every checkout but that's just bleh.